# Renaming a path to file in Flask

Tags: python, flask

My Flask app serves high resolution images after a user signs up and pays for them. The images are stored in `/static/img/wall/` directory, and are named as `wall_001.jpg`, `wall_002.jpg`, and so on. I need to stick with this naming scheme for now. The numbers basically act as IDs and I use them throughout the app.

When I display the image after payment, I use the direct path to the image `<img src="/static/img/wall/wall_001.jpg" alt="Wallpaper">`.

If someone wanted to, they could easily paste that link in a new tab and access `wall_002.jpg, wall_003.jpg` and so on.

Is there a way I can rename the path to the image, or randomize the filename when the image is served *after* payment?

I used Flask-Resize/Flask-Images as a way to handle this issue because they create a new file and store in a cache folder. But am [having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593231/flask-images-and-flask-resize-result-in-ioerror) with those extensions in production.

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate question. It's a different scenario. My question deals with not just logins, but also payments. Hence, there is a need to randomize/rename/mask the original urls.

Comment: Try adding Authentication and a Login page.

Comment: @rocksteady I'm already using Flask-Login with OAuth2 for social networks. I guess I'm not sure how to restrict access to those files in `/static/img/wall/wall_001.jpg` (and so on)...

Answer (score 0):

Create a hard `os.link()` or soft `os.symlink()` link to the file then display that name to the customer.  The name could be generated randomly using python random()

```
    import random
    import string

    def randomword(length):
      return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(length))
```

Code ref, user "sth" on stackoverflow

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  The question is how to prevent advertising application filesystem structure publicly.